# SonarQube 5.0.1 - Error declaring a false-positive issue

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, false-positive

I've a "Failed" message displayed when I declare a "false-positive" issue from the Web UI of Sonarqube (5.0.1).
A 400 error is returned with this response : "Transition from state RESOLVED does not exist: falsepositive"

But the issue is declared "unresolved" in the web ui (both on global issues and project page) and it broke the build (since I'm using Build Breaker plugin).

I have a doubt on the shown issue because it should be logically solved by my previous commit (cache problem ?).

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when the ElasticSearch index of issues is out of sync with the database. You should stop your server, remove the `$SQ_HOME/data/es` directory and restart the server. It might take some time, depending on the number of issues in your database, but it should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. 
Is there a way to purge the cache without restarting the server ? 
How and why ES became out of sync with database ? Is there a bug already declared ? If not, how can I declare it (since I'm not able to create one in SonarQube's JIRA). 
We've many projects analysed and we are confronted with this problem several times per week. It's painful to restart SonarQube each time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a shame but no, there is currently (2015-06-16) no identified bug that causes desynchronization of ES. It seems to happen quite often in the wild, but we have not been able to reproduce it on our instances (which are continuously deployed).